# Invalid frame ID even if the TF tree is produced correctly

Tags: urdf, robot-state-publisher, joint-state-publisher, tf2-ros, ros-foxy

I am having a hard time understanding the production of the TF tree. I have a robot which is visualized correctly both on Rviz and Gazebo. The transmissions and gazebo plugins work fine such that I can command the robot with differential drive topics. However, I see a warning on the terminal about the links which are not connected to the base_link via fixed joint. Please see the screenshot such that the 'left_wheel' and 'right_wheel' are connected properly according to the TF map but the terminal gives a warning. Can some explain to me what is wrong here?

By the way, Rviz fails if I choose the fixed frame 'odom' instead of 'base_link'.[image: base] [image: odom]

Thank you

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It looks like there may be useful and relevant error information, but unfortunately most of it is hidden in a screenshot of a terminal. Please copy-paste the terminal output (formatted as code) so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your tf tree, I see that you have some transforms with timestamps in the range of the 40s and others that are many orders of magnitude larger. (Aka current time since the epoch) with inconsistent timestamps the tree cannot be traversed at any queried time.

Static transforms are valid at all times which is why you can render some transforms.

But this suggests that you have some nodes with `using_sim_time` and some not. Make sure that it's enabled on all nodes.